# iOS display backtrace with method names also in released product

Tags: ios, objective-c, backtrace, symbolicate

I wanted to have a backtrace with the classes and method names displayed every time the app crashes. I managed to do it in debug mode, using this code (the `printTrace` function just prints the string on a file.):

```
void HandleException(NSException *exception)
{
    [SILogManager printTrace:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"******************** CRASH *********************"]];
    [SILogManager printTrace:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-> Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]]];
}
```

Although this won't work when the app is released, because it will produce a stacktrace like this one:

```
******************** CRASH *********************
-> Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x27b5f60f <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35613c77 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x27a733a7 <redacted> + 178
    3   iSelz POS                           0x000bf6c7 iSelz POS + 403143
    4   iSelz POS                           0x000bf099 iSelz POS + 401561
    5   iSelz POS                           0x000dda31 iSelz POS + 526897
    6   CFNetwork                           0x276b7eed <redacted> + 56
    7   CFNetwork                           0x276b7ea7 <redacted> + 182
    8   CFNetwork                           0x276b7f99 <redacted> + 36
    9   CFNetwork                           0x275cceef <redacted> + 78
    10  CFNetwork                           0x2766976d <redacted> + 60
    11  CFNetwork                           0x275bdd71 <redacted> + 60
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x27a705a1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
    13  CFNetwork                           0x275bdc2b <redacted> + 182
    14  CFNetwork                           0x275bdaf1 <redacted> + 216
    15  CFNetwork                           0x275bd98d <redacted> + 48
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x27b25fd7 <redacted> + 14
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x27b253eb <redacted> + 222
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x27b23a69 <redacted> + 768
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x27a70b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x27a70943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x2edf8051 GSEventRunModal + 136
    22  UIKit                               0x2b0666f1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    23  iSelz POS                           0x00066aab iSelz POS + 39595
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x35bafaaf <redacted> + 2
)
```

And I don't find it very useful.
I've also already tried to call `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols` manually, but it doesn't work!

In the project properties, I have the following settings, that should copy all the dynamic symbols when building, so I still can't figure out why it isn't working!

[image: Build options]
[image: Deployment options]

What can I do to have this feature also in the released app? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!